# What is the reason for error "Resource in project is the subject of a conflict" while trying to recreate a cloudsql instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I am trying to create a cloudsql instance with the following command:

```
gcloud beta sql instances create sql-instance-1 --tier=db-f1-micro --region=asia-south1 --network=default --storage-type=HDD --storage-size=10GB --authorized-networks=XX.XXX.XX.XX/XX
```

The instance sql-instance-1 is something I need not running all the time. So I create an sqldump file and when I need the database I create it. When I run this command it fails with the following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.sql.instances.create) Resource in project [my-project-id] is the subject of a conflict: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.
```

From what I understand the gcloud is complaining that instance name was used before although the instance is already deleted. When I change the name to a new unused name the command works fine. The problem with this is I need to give a new name every time I re-create the instance from the dump.

My questions are:

- Is this expected behavior i.e. should name of cloud-sql instance be unique and not used before within a project.
- I also found that **--network** option is not recognized with gcloud. Seems to work only with gcloud beta as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance). When is this expected to become GA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed expected behaviour. From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/delete-instance):

> You cannot reuse an instance name for up to a week after you have
>   deleted an instance.

Regarding the `--network` flag and it's schedule for GA, there is no ETA for its release outside of beta. However, it's release will be listed in the [Google Cloud SDK Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes), which you can get updates from by subscribing to the [google-cloud-sdk-announce group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sdk-announce.)

Comment: Thank you @Joan Grau. When I click on the link to subscribe to **google-cloud-sdk-announce** group, I get an error message "There is no group called google-cloud-sdk-announce".

Comment: Are you logged in with a gmail account? I can access the group by this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-sdk-announce) just fine